# Python regex and splitting

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
mystr = "K1_L1_L2  XX"
```

I want to break it to the following format

```
K1 L1 L2  XX
```

where K1, L1, L2 can be anything but have this format of a char followed by a number. I am doing this in python using the following regex:

```
a = "K1_L1_L2  XX"
re.split("[\c\d\_]+",a)
```

which gives me the following output

```
['K', 'L', 'L', '  ', '.', '']
```

but I want something like this

```
['K1', 'L1', 'L2', '  ', '.', '']
```

what is the possible workaround?

Comment: Something else worth noting is that `\c` is not a valid character class. You can use `\w`, which is a shorthand for `[0-9a-zA-Z_]` when used on ASCII strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are problems with the code you have included in your example above. I would edit them but I'm not 100% sure what you are looking for.

The following:

```
import re

a = "K1_L1_L2  XX"
print re.split("[ _]", a)
```

will print:

```
['K1', 'L1', 'L2', '', 'XX']
```

Comment: Thanks. this was way simpler using this !

Comment: If you're happy with this, don't forget to accept this answer. This will save time for other users.

Answer (score 0):

maybe

```
re.split("([A-Za-z]\d)",a)
```

?